# For loop extra condition

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

I have a for loop that goes through a couple of arrays and assigns some values after doing some basic math. My question is: Is there a way to make sure that this for loop ONLY iterates while an additional condition is true?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ci); $i++) {
    $PIDvalue = $ci[$i]["PID"];
    $datevalue = $pi[$i]["datetime"];
    $pp_tcvalue = $ci[$i]["pp_tc"] - $pi[$i]["pp_tc"];
    $pp_trvalue = $ci[$i]["pp_tr"] - $pi[$i]["pp_tr"];
    $bp_tcvalue = $ci[$i]["bp_tc"] - $pi[$i]["bp_tc"];
    $emailvalue = $ci[$i]["email"];
```

So I want something like this...

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($ci); $i++) {
    if($ci[$i]["email"] === $pi[$i]["email"]) {
    $PIDvalue = $ci[$i]["PID"];
    $datevalue = $pi[$i]["datetime"];
    $pp_tcvalue = $ci[$i]["pp_tc"] - $pi[$i]["pp_tc"];
    $pp_trvalue = $ci[$i]["pp_tr"] - $pi[$i]["pp_tr"];
    $bp_tcvalue = $ci[$i]["bp_tc"] - $pi[$i]["bp_tc"];
    $emailvalue = $ci[$i]["email"];
```

If they don't match, I would assign a value of "0" or something.

Comment: Whats wrong with your current code, should work as expected

Comment: @user574632 not if that trailing `}` is unclosed (Could just be a question typo though.. )

Comment: @user574632 I'm running into an issue - my issue is that users sign up and pay for a service, and then they cancel their subscription (which is fine) but they still get counted and it messes up the for loop. My issue may be my queries, but I don't want to rewrite them because they are so detailed. I'm looking for a possible better solution.

Comment: @MackieeE There is much more code, I just left off the non-important stuff to the question.

Comment: @ChaseC sure, what i meant is what is wrong with your code above - the if statement should do exactly what you want. If not i have misunderstood your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional condition to the for-loop, making it pretty much unreadable:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ci), $ci[$i]["email"] === $pi[$i]["email"]; $i++)
```

but I would rather `break` the loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ci); $i++) {
    if ($ci[$i]["email"] !== $pi[$i]["email"]) break;
    $PIDvalue = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add that in your for condition, like that :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($ci) && $ci[$i]["email"] === $pi[$i]["email"]; $i++) {
```

When the second condition computes to false, the loop will stop running.